# Kubernetes | AWS-EKS | could not resolve host name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I created four services, two ClusterIP and two NodePort services. Against each service I spin up two containers as shown below.

However, the problem is some services work fine and some while calling from inside the container not able to resolve the service hostname.

**While narrowing down a problem, I created a below matrix:-**

```
TYPES   NodePort    ClusterIp
NodePort    Pass    Fail
ClusterIp   Pass    Fail
```

> which explains:-
>
> 1. A request (curl –v http://order-service-ip/swagger/index.html) from inside the container of aggregator-service(nodePort) fails and throws
>      could not resolve hostname error but vice-versa works. That is hitting
>      a request (curl –v http://aggregator-service/swagger/index.html) from
>      inside the container of order-service-ip works.
> 2. In the same way, calling of nodeport service from another nodeport container works.
> 3. But, calling of clusterIP service from a ClusterIp container fails and not able to resolve the hostname.

Surprisingly, a cluster IP container is able to resolve the hostname of Nodeport service and traversing back from the same nodePort container to the same ClusterIp service does not work.

Any suggestions are appreciated. I am stuck with this problem for more than four days now.

**Here are the details of pods and services and end points are also working fine.**

```
NAME                                           ........                     READY   STATUS    
nodeport-aggegator-deployment-64497699d-6jqz4       1/1     Running      
nodeport-aggegator-deployment-64497699d-jx8n6       1/1     Running   
clusterip-order-deployment-ip-594ff6b59b-pb4bp          1/1     Running   
clusterip-order-deployment-ip-594ff6b59b-rbhj4            1/1     Running  
nodeport-resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-qvd59      1/1     Running  
nodeport-resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-zjrh7        1/1     Running  
clusterip-product-deployment-ip-7589c74bfc-dx8l4         1/1     Running  
clusterip-product-deployment-ip-7589c74bfc-mbqs5       1/1     Running  


NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP         PORT(S)                        
aggregator-service           NodePort       10.100.66.74     <none>             8081:30392/TCP,443:30891/TCP   
order-service-ip               ClusterIP      10.100.118.19     <none>             8010/TCP,443/TCP               
resources-service             NodePort       10.100.81.65     <none>             8001:31076/TCP,443:30429/TCP   
product-service-ip            ClusterIP      10.100.66.14      <none>             8011/TCP,443/TCP               
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.100.0.1          <none>             443/TCP
```

Thanks

Comment: Are your container alpine based image ?

Comment: No its a windows based container. But a problem is very strange, I even changed security inbound rules  of AWS to allow all the traffic on all the ports.

Comment: Could you add the output for:   `kubectl get svc -o wide` and yamls for "Against each service I spin up two containers as shown below."? Additionally for "curl –v http://order-service-ip/swagger/index.html", do you call it as it is written, or with the IP instead of  order-service-ip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with in a code which had a port conflict. The one being used to redirect from Nodeport to ClusterIp was not correct.